# Conditional formatting for partial matches in range in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have the following sample data, I can use the following formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$5, A1) > 1` to find exact matches which finds "Narf" and "Narf", however whatever formula I try to find partial matches which should match "Dooze" and "Dooz 2", nothing seems to work.

One I tried to write is: `=AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$E$5, A1) > 1, NOT(EXACT(A1, UNIQUE($A$1:$E$5))))`

There is no "Name" header btw.

| Name | Name | Name | Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Drog | Kamic 1 | Gehr | Smoked | Yeahnice 2 |
| Radi | Moon | Quackers | Narf | EJ |
| Mlad | Whakz | Reaper 2 | Terroraxe | Compz |
| Cleo 1 | Nighteyes | Oliver 2 | Narf | Espi |
| Dooze | Pureshadow | Hewston | Dooz 2 | Corbs |

I'm not locked into conditional formatting so if there is an easier way with just using the formula in a random cell to display maybe a count or the string of the results, which is what I initially tried but didn't seem to work either.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the criteria to consider something a "partial match"?

Comment: Just two strings with any matching words I guess? Like "Dooze" and "Dooz 2" should match since the "Dooz" part from the start should match, even if it matches "2" and "1" together or whatever is fine too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to consider matches in any word or number that may be contained you can use this formula. Adapt the range A1:E5 with your actual range:

```
=LAMBDA(all,{all,BYROW(INDEX(SPLIT(all," ")),LAMBDA(a,IFERROR(JOIN(", ",(FILTER(all,all<>INDEX(a,,1),all<>JOIN(" ",a),REGEXMATCH(all,JOIN("|",FILTER(a,a<>"")))))))))})(FLATTEN(A1:E5))
```

It returns this result with a first column with all the values, and a second one with the partial matches:

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution! Is it possible to filter the results to only return ones with matches?

Comment: Use QUERY: `=QUERY(the-previous-formula,"Where Col2 is not null",)` Fill in the formula yourself 

Comment: Hey thanks I got that working! I just realised this formula only works if the string has matching numbers, like in your example "Kamic 1" and "Cleo 1" appear, which is fine, but if i just do "Kamic" and "Kamic" in the data set, it doesn't return that



Edit: seems to work for anything that isn't an "exact" match, can it also include exact matches? I'm not having much luck myself trying to edit the formula

Comment: I changed the formula to as so:
`=QUERY(LAMBDA(all,{all,BYROW(INDEX(SPLIT(all," ")),LAMBDA(a,IFERROR(JOIN(", ",(FILTER(all,all<>JOIN(" ",a),REGEXMATCH(all,JOIN("|",FILTER(a,a<>"")))))))))})(FLATTEN({'SHEET'!A27:E31})), "WHERE Col2 is not null", )`

Seems to work, Col2 is showing the initial name though but it's probably good enough, tyvm! Lmk if any better solutions if not all good =)

Comment: Could you show me which case is showing? the formula should filter out the ones that are equal to itself You can try to change all<>JOIN(" ",a) with TRIM(a)<>JOIN(" ",a)